# Why jpa return empty in a @OneToMany if there are data in the other table

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have a OneToMany relationchip in a entity. when I do the findAll JPA bring me the data from all the  @ManyToOne but bring me [] empty for the @OneToMany (the collection come empty).

This is the how is the relation in the main entity:

```
public class Emprendimientos implements Serializable {
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "logoId")
private Collection<LogosEmprendimientos> logosEmprendimientos;
```

The code in the other entity:

```
public class LogosEmprendimientos implements Serializable {
.
.
.
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Emprendimientos emprendimiento;
```

The result of the findAll of Emprendimientos for the collection is

```
.
.
"logosEmprendimientos": [],
```

I have tow records in tha data base in the LogosEmprendimientos related to the Emprendimientos record in colsulting
[image]

Why it retur empty and how can i solve it?

Thanks!

the father class (Emprendimientos)
[image]

the son class (Cofundadores)
[image]

that birng a infinite loop when I consult it

Comment: `mappedBy = "logoId"` <- The mappedBy annotation should point to the attribute that maps the relation on the other side. In your case i can't see andy `logoId` attribute, instead it seems to be `emprendimiento`

Comment: Hi @OHGODSPIDERS I fix it but start with and infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

In `@OneToMany` relationship, the `mappedBy` is the field's name on the other class. In this case is `emprendimiento`:

```
public class Emprendimientos implements Serializable {
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "emprendimiento")
private Collection<LogosEmprendimientos> logosEmprendimientos;
```

For `@ManyToOne` relationship you have to add also `@JoinColumn(name="EMPRENDIMIENTOS_ID")` where the `EMPRENDIMIENTOS_ID` is the primary key in `Emprendimientos` table which is the foreign key in `LogosEmprendimientos` table.

```
public class LogosEmprendimientos implements Serializable {
.
.
.
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPRENDIMIENTOS_ID")
private Emprendimientos emprendimiento;
```

Comment: how can i avoit infinite loop?

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Comment: Hi @gkatiforis I post the code can you take a look please